# connecting arrows between vertical and curved line

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to make a few alterations to the following figure:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% draw the ground
\draw (0,0) -- (8.5,0) .. controls (8.5,-1) and (10,-1).. (11,-1) -- (14,-1);
% draw lake surface
\draw [snake = snake,segment amplitude =.4mm, segment length = 5mm] (8.5,0) -- (14,0);
% draw the wind velocity field
\draw[very thick,gray](12,0)--(12,5);
\draw (12,0)..controls(12.5,2) and(14,3) ..(14,5);% draw profile
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

From this figure I would like to add horizontal arrow lines from the straight vertical line to the curved line. My attempt:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% draw the ground
\draw (0,0) -- (8.5,0) .. controls (8.5,-1) and (10,-1).. (11,-1) -- (14,-1);
% draw lake surface
\draw [snake = snake,segment amplitude =.4mm, segment length = 5mm] (8.5,0) -- (14,0);
% draw the wind velocity field
\draw[very thick,gray](12,0)--(12,5);
\draw (12,0)..controls(12.5,2) and(14,3) ..(14,5);% draw profile
\foreach \y in {2,3,5}
\foreach \x in {12.5,14,14}{
\draw[=>stealth,->](12,\y)--(\x,\y);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

which is obviously incorrect, but I cant seem to solve this. Also, how could I make the horizontal lines be drawn 5 time evenly spaced vertically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `snakes` library is deprecated, use the `decorations.pathmorphing` library instead.

To find the right points on the curved line I have used the `intersections` library.
The curved line is named `curve`.

In a loop that iterates over `\y` from `1` to `5` a path is named `horizontal` that goes from `(12, \y)` to `(15, \y)` (so that it crosses the curved path). The intersection of `curve` and `horizontal` is named `intersection-1` and is used in a drawn path.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,arrows,intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
% draw the ground
\draw (0,0) -- (8.5,0) .. controls (8.5,-1) and (10,-1).. (11,-1) -- (14,-1);
% draw lake surface
\draw [decorate, decoration={snake,amplitude =.4mm, segment length = 5mm}] (8.5,0) -- (14,0);
% draw the wind velocity field
\draw[very thick,gray](12,0)--(12,5);
\draw[name path=curve] (12,0)..controls(12.5,2) and(14,3) ..(14,5);% draw profile
\foreach \y in {1,...,5}{
    \path[name path=horizontal] (12,\y) -- + (3,0);
    \draw[-stealth,name intersections={of=curve and horizontal}] (12,\y) -- (intersection-1);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]